# Images not showing on configurable products

Tags: magento2, image, magento2.4.2

I have all of the needed attributes in the attribute set, but none of the images are showing on configurable products.
They're visible on the backend, and I see them when I add the images to the cart, they just won't show up in gallery or product view.

What can I do about this?

There's a $fotoramaElement.fotorama is not a function error in the console which I think is related, but I don't know how to fix it

In my child theme requirejs-confing.js I added this, but it's not doing anything.

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'fotorama/fotorama':  'fotorama/fotorama'
    },
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },      
    },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting file and folder permission again on pub/ then run
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done it for simple products. New error for configurable

Comment: Looks like it only worked as a one off. Isn't working anymore